# HttpURLConnection doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to consume webservice datas in my android projet

```
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://ip.jsontest.com/");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode(); //fail
            Log.d("","success!");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
```

The code fails when `conn.getResponseCode()` is called.
The same thing when `conn.getInputStream()` or `conn.getContent()` are called.

No exceptions are thrown. 
`conn.disconnect()` (in the finally block) is executed just after `conn.connect()`

In my AndroidManifest I have

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**EDIT**

I have the same problem using AsyncTask

```
public class DataAccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //snackbar.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        String stringUrl = strings[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();

            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }

            return new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s == null) {
            //resultsTextView.setText("Erreur");
        } else {
            //resultsTextView.setText(s);
        }
        //snackbar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: use the class that extends Async Task

Comment: Check if you have internet in your device.

Comment: I have the same problem using AsycTask

Comment: Yes I have internet on the device

Comment: I copy your code and run it...works. what is your device os version?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the webservice with postman application? Also sometimes firewalls block connections. Try disabling your firewall and the run your app

Comment: What is the point of returning from catch block ?

Comment: Device version is Android 7.0 I've tryied with Android 6.0. Still have the problem.

Comment: Codus what os version did you use?

Comment: I would advice you to install postman so that you can confirm that you get a response from webservice. It is pretty easy to use. Have you checked the firewall i proposed? I had some issues with my firewall when trying to connect to a service i had built

Comment: Log your responseCode to check if it is getting `200`. else there is something wrong with the server

Comment: if your targetSdkVersion>=23 you should add runtime permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response code 200 is meant for successful HTTP requests.
So, replace `if (response != 200)` with `if (response == 200)` .
Change your permission with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

Comment: I have put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in my manifest. I've removed the if statement (response == 200). Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class example extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link="give the link here";
            String data= null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
```

// If u want to send some data using some values use below encoder else dont neet
                    data = URLEncoder.encode("one", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(a, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("two", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(b, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("three", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(c, "UTF-8");

```
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                osw.write(data);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line,sb="";
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb+=line;
                }
                return sb;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return  new String(e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            // It will get the response from server
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you linking it with PHP script??

Answer (score 0):

Do you getting Something like thread StrictMode ???
Try Calling this before Executing Async Task.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .detectAll()
     .penaltyLog()
     .build();  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```